# Does Javascript filter() perform type coercion by default?

Tags: javascript, filter, type-coercion

I know about Javascript type coercion (== vs ===).

I'm looking at the filter() function. It seems that it performs type coercion by default. Is this correct? Here is the code:

```
var x = [1,2,'hi']

console.log(x.filter(String)); // [ 1, 2, 'hi' ]
console.log(x.filter(Number)); // [ 1, 2]
```

If I didn't want this to be the case would I have to add a callback to the filter function? I was surprised this worked in its current form as I thought it ALWAYS required a callback parameter.

Comment: filter() is supposed to keep elements for which the callback returns a truthy value. Which your test results reflect. What do you mean about requiring a parameter? The `String()` and `Number()` functions both take a parameter...

Comment: It would appear, at least at a glance, that it does. String and Number are callbacks in this case, ran as String(1/2/"hi"). String("hi") == true returns false, however !!String("hi") returns true. Not sure what this means implementation-wise however, but it would appear that it runs the values through the function, then coerces the result to a boolean.

Comment: Ahhhh. I didn't know that String and Number were in fact functions

Comment: or at least it didn't occur to me, though looking at the code and how filter() works I guess that should have bee obvious

Comment: please watch `0` at `x.filter(Number)` --> false!

Comment: @nina yes. That is strange...  What is the reason for implementing the Number construction like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not check if the elements are String or Number. What it does is this:

`String(1)` returns `'1'` => truthy => passes filter.
`Number('hi')` returns `NaN` => falsy => does not pass filter.

What you want to do can be achieved with a function:

```
function checkString(el) {
    return (typeof el === 'string');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `String` and `Number` Global object will convert, if its possible to convert. [the LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Parameters).

and it says,

> "Anything to be converted to a string."

and about the `Number`. [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Description)

> If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN

NaN is taken a false,